# How to avoid counting all div elements in html page [JQUERY]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to count only some div elments, not all. Suppose you have this html markup:

```
<div id="box">
 <div>
     <div>
     </div>
 </div>
<div>
     <div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to count the `<div>` that are children directly from div with id="box". In this example the count of these divs is 2 and not 4.

This is my Jquery code:

```
var count=$('#box')find('div').length;
console.log(count) // the result is 4 because counts all divs
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can count child elements:

```
<div id="box">
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var count=$('#box').find('div').length;
    alert(count) // the result is 4 because counts all divs

    var count=$('#box > div').length;
    alert(count) // the result is 2 because counts all divs within the first one
</script>
```

**Running script:** https://jsfiddle.net/6yg3e0f9/2/

If you run this as a html file, you will see the alert(4) and the alert(2) both work.

Comment: I think the second example is working by coincidence only in this case.  It's actually selecting the *grand-child* elements, instead of the *child* elements.  Which happen to have the same count.  Observe:  https://jsfiddle.net/6yg3e0f9/1/

Comment: Good catch. I didn't read that well and thought this was what he wanted. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` will traverse the entire node, whereas `.children()` will examine only the immediate descendants:

```
var count = $('#box').children('div').length;
```

Conversely, you can use `>` in your selector to also specify immediate children directly.  Something like this:

```
var count = $('#box > div').length;
```